# Python - tuple index out of range, but i dont think it is

Tags: python, tuples

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated - as can be seen from the code I am just trying to get it to print each 'card' out. This code currently prints cards Ace - King of hearts but when changing suits it then runs into tuple index out of range. Very new to python and just experimenting with it so I do understand there are easier ways to do what I am trying to do. Many thanks:)

```
suits = "Hearts" , "Clubs" , "Diamonds" , "Spades"
values = "Ace" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine" , "Ten" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King"

i = -1
j = -1
while i <= 3:
    i = i + 1
    while j <= 12:
        j = j + 1
        print (values[j] , " of " , suits[j])
```

Comment: After you loop through all the Hearts, you forgot to reset `j` - so you start with the 13 of Clubs for the next loop.  Note that all of this can be much more simply expressed via `for suit in suits:` / `for value in values:`.

Comment: When you don't think the value should be out of range, but Python reports that it is, you should first check what the value actually is by debugging. Then you can re-check your logic to figure out why it has the value it actually has, instead of the value you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `print (values[j] , " of " , suits[j])`, you're using j as variable for both values and suits.

Just change the variable for suits to i and place the declaration of j inside the first while loop.

However, another - better - method of achieving what you're trying to do is to use for loops. This way your code is much cleaner you don't have to keep track of the index.

Here it is rewritten with for loops:

```
suits = "Hearts" , "Clubs" , "Diamonds" , "Spades"
values = "Ace" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine" , "Ten" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King"

for suit in suits:
    for value in values:
        print(value, "of", suit)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that method is much more logical and works better - much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is never used. Based on the fact that you are looping in the range of 3, I can only assume you meant to use i for the indexes of suits. Which is where you have a problem of index out of range.

Also you don't reset j each time you iterate. I would move the declaration of j to inside the first while loop.

```
suits = "Hearts" , "Clubs" , "Diamonds" , "Spades"
values = "Ace" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine" , "Ten" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King"

i = -1
while i <= 3:
    j = -1 # Note where j is now placed.
    i = i + 1
    while j <= 12:
        j = j + 1
        print (values[j] , " of " , suits[i]) # Note the change on this line suits[i]
```

As another aside you can also write the addition to each of the variables in a cleaner manner.

```
i = i + 1
```

is the same as

```
i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you - I can see where i went wrong now, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

This is much simpler to do without index wrangling.

```
from itertools import product


for suit, rank in product(suits, values):
    print(f'{rank} of {suit}')
```